# Angular CLI and java war deployable, unable to reload specific path

Tags: java, angular, typescript, war

I've developed an application using Angular CLI, and I wish to deploy this application on a EAP server.

To do this, I've hade to make some modifications to the project settings.
These modifications include:

- Setting `deployUrl` in `angular-cli.json`. If I do not do this, the server can't find my generated script files. If I deploy deployable.war to my server, all scripts and stylesheets have to be referenced like this when they are included: `/deployable/script.js`. Setting `deployUrl` to the name of the deployable resolves this.
- To get assets to work (the default assets folder, under src/assets), I have to supply a base-href to the cli build command; `ng build -prod --base-href=./`. This allows the server to find both favicon and files under the asset folder.

When I run `ng build -prod --base-href=./`, I've set the output folder to src/main/webapp which is the default folder for the maven-war-plugin. When the build is done, I run `mvn clean install` and deploy the resulting file to my EAP server.

However, using this approach for production, the only way to access the app is through `http://hostname/deployablename` (I'm guessing this triggers script loading in index.html), otherwise it seems like it's not bootstrapping correctly. This makes it impossible  to reload a page or bookmark a page, i.e. going directly to `http://hostname/deployablename/somePath`will result in a 404.

I was expecting that setting `deployUrl` would solve the problem for my assets too, but it seems that this parameter has no effect on resources referenced in html files, which is where I have references to my favicon and images.

With these settings, this is the final index.html that is generated:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Laman</title>
  <base href="./">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link href="/deployable/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/deployable/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the structure in the result war file:

```
war
|-- /assets
|-- /META-INF
|-- /WEB-INF
|-- favicon.ico
|-- index.html
|-- styles.css
`-- scripts.js
```

For reference, this is my folder structure:

```
project
|-- appsrc
|   |-- assets
|   |-- src
|   |   |-- routing-module.ts
|   |   `-- bootstrap-module.ts
|   |-- index.html
|   `-- favicon.ico
`-- src
    `-- main
        `-- webapp
```

appsrc is the working directory, the build script places the final files in src/main/webapp.

My routing module looks like this.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'template/:system/:name/:version',  component: TemplateDetailComponent },
  { path: 'template/upload', component: TemplateUploadComponent },
  { path: 'templates',  component: TemplateListComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/templates', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: TemplateListComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {};
```

So, in a nutshell, I've got everything to work except bookmarking / reloading a specific path.

How do I enable a war deployable and an angular application to work nicely together? If you need any more information about my setup or anything else, please tell me and I will supply it.

Comment: Don't use ./ as base href. use /deployable/

Comment: If I use that, I have to access my application using `host/deployable/deployable`. EAP uses the file name of the deployable as a path, and then Angular appends an additional path with the exact same name. This is the result: `http://localhost:8080/deployable/deployable/templates`. Even with this, I can't reload or bookmark.

Comment: Because you use /deployable as your deployUrl. Don't. Since you already have /deployable as your base href, the script and CSS paths will all be prepended with /deployable/